# How install GTK+ and all their dependencies?

Tags: c, user-interface, gtk, debian, glib

Recently I tried install GTK+ on debian wheezy... but... i had a lot problems. My first problem was Glib2.40 i don't know why when i'am trying to install appears... problem leaving a directory or entering a directory... so I can't execute properly "make install" I have the problem with all the requirements of GTK+, o would like to know a simple way to install GTK+.... I tried by the boring way.... download the source package and ./configure etc etc and the fast way sudo apt-get install "".

Could somebody help me?

Greetings!!!

Answer (score 0):

Installing from source packages can be a good way to break your system, especially for relatively low-level packages such as glib which a lot of other packages depend on.  If I were you I would [use jhbuild](https://wiki.gnome.org/HowDoI/Jhbuild) instead.